# Typescript access to private static fields within same class

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering what's the way to access a private static field within the same class assuming that class isn't *exported*.

```
module Test {
    class Template {
        private static ext = '.hbs';
        private static basePath = 'WebContent/templates/';
        private static templatesFolder = 'templates';
        private static partialsFolder = 'partials';
        private static paymentMethodsFolder = 'paymentMethods';

        public static template(templateName, data): string{
            return Handlebars.templates[Test.Template.basePath + this.templatesFolder + '/' + templateName + this.ext];
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to access to the static variables within the `static template` function. I don't want to export the class, because I want to encapsulate the logic so it's not usable from the browser.

What's the way to go here? I started with `this` because it wasn't static at first, but I changed my mind and I'm stuck now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can just type the class name like below (so the same as you have now but without the module name (Test)

```
Handlebars.templates[Template.basePath + Template.templatesFolder + '/' + templateName + Template.ext];
```

You can't access the `public static template` function now from outside the module because it is in the class which isn't exported.

If you move that function out of the class in the module and instead of `public static` make it `export function` you can call it outside the module and it should work correctly.

Comment: It was so easy, I knew it had to be possible, just forgot how to do it! Thanks.